# Do we have non-trivial solutions for $\frac{e^{ad X_0}-1}{ad X_0}X=0$?

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $k$ be $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite dimensional Lie algebra over $k$. Let $X_0$ be a fixed element in $\mathfrak{g}$ and consider the equation
$$
X+\frac{1}{2!}[X_0,X]+\frac{1}{3!}[X_0,[X_0,X]]+\ldots=0.
$$
It can be rewritten as
$$
\frac{e^{ad X_0}-1}{ad X_0}X=0.
$$

If $\mathfrak{g}$ is abelian, then the only solution to the above equation is $X=0$.

> > My question is: in general do we have non-trivial solutions to the above equation? If so, what do they look like. It will be appreciated if you can give me relevant references.

Comment: What does this sum mean when it has infinitely many nonzero terms?

Comment: What is the meaning of $\ldots$ for a Lie algebra over a field?  For a finite-dimensional Lie algebra over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ we can talk about convergence of the series, but in general?

Comment: Yes I will modify them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is for a finite-dimensional Lie algebra (or more generally a Banach Lie algebra) over the complex numbers,
$\text{ad }X_0$ is a bounded linear operator on $\mathfrak g$, and we want an element of
the null space of $g(\text{ad} X_0)$ for the entire function $g(z) = (\exp(z)-1)/z$.
By the spectral mapping theorem, $g(\text{ad} X_0)$ is invertible if and only if
$g(\lambda) \ne 0$ for all $\lambda$ in the spectrum of $\text{ad} X_0$.  On the other
hand, if $X$ is an eigenvector of $\text{ad} X_0$ for eigenvalue $\lambda$ and
$g(\lambda) = 0$, then $g(\text{ad} X_0) X = 0$.  In this case the zeros of $g$ are
$2 \pi i n$ for nonzero integers $n$.